# Calculating the winner in a tic tac game using react hook and js

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, return-value, destructuring

I am new to javaScript and react hook, working on a tic tac game but I don't understand the below **if statement**, I need an explanation as to what the if statement is saying in English. my calculate winner function below:

```
export function calculateWinner(squares) {
    const Lines = [
      [0, 1, 2],
      [3, 4, 5],
      [6, 7, 8],
      [0, 3, 6],
      [1, 4, 7],
      [2, 5, 8],
      [0, 4, 8],
      [2, 4, 6],
    ];
    for (let i = 0; i < Lines.length; i++) {
      const [a, b, c] = Lines[i];
      if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
        return squares[a];
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code with comments on what it does:

```js
if (                           // If
  squares[a] &&                // there is a value in square a, and
  squares[a] === squares[b] && // it is equal to what is in square b, and
  squares[a] === squares[c]    // it is equal to what is in square c
) {
  return squares[a];           // return the value in square a
}
```

Some background about the other code, even though you didn't ask:

- You haven't shown what `squares` is, but from the example we can conclude that it is an array of `9` values. When a square is empty, it needs to contain a "falsey" value (e.g. `null`, `0`, `false` or `""`). If it contains a player's move, it should contain a "truethy" value (e.g. `"x"` and "o", `-1` and `1`, or even `"1"` and `"0"`.
- `Lines` is a collection of index-trios that make up winning lines. So remember: `a`, `b` and `c` will be *indices*, making `square[a]` essentially read as "the value in square of index a".
- The reason you need `if (squares[a])` is because for an empty line `squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]` would be true

Some isolated examples:

```js
console.log(
  // The [0, 3, 6] Line for X
  calculateWinner(
    [  "X", null, null,
       "O",  "X",  "O",
      null, null,  "X"  ]
  ),
  // The [2, 5, 8] Line for O
  calculateWinner(
    [  "X", null,  "O",
       "X",  "X",  "O",
      null, null,  "O"  ]
  ),
  // A game without a winner
  calculateWinner(
    [  "X",  "O",  "O",
       "O",  "X",  "X",
       "X",  "X",  "O"  ]
  ),
  // An empty game (again, no winner)
  calculateWinner(
    [  null, null, null,
       null, null, null,
       null, null, null ]
  )
);

function calculateWinner(squares) {
    const Lines = [
      [0, 1, 2],
      [3, 4, 5],
      [6, 7, 8],
      [0, 3, 6],
      [1, 4, 7],
      [2, 5, 8],
      [0, 4, 8],
      [2, 4, 6],
    ];
    for (let i = 0; i < Lines.length; i++) {
      const [a, b, c] = Lines[i];
      if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
        return squares[a];
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I still don't get how that if statement translate to the winning line. if squares is an Array(9).fill(null)  which is to be replaced with either X or O onclick.  when the squares array is filled with X or  O,  squares[a] will never be equal to squares[b] or squares[c]. I will post below the react function where the calculateWinner function is used.

Comment: function Game() {
    const [gameBoard, setGameBoard] = useState(Array(9).fill(null))
    const [nextTurn, setNextTurn] = useState(true)
    const winner = calculateWinner(gameBoard)
   const handleClick = (i) => {
       
        const gameBoardCopy = [...gameBoard]
        

          if(winner || gameBoardCopy[i]) return

              gameBoardCopy[i]= nextTurn ? 'X' : 'O'

        setGameBoard(gameBoardCopy)
        setNextTurn(!nextTurn)
        
    }

Comment: _"when the squares array is filled with X or O, squares[a] will never be equal to squares[b] or squares[c]"_ This is not true. The `a`, `b` and `c` vars are references to indices, defined by the elements of the `Lines` array. I added a runnable example that notes how a winning Line relates to a `squares` array.

Comment: wow! Thank you so much, is very clear now.